# Problem with fork exec kill when redirecting output in perl

Tags: perl, redirect, fork, kill

I created a script in perl to run programs with a timeout. If the program being executed takes longer then the timeout than the script kills this program and returns the message "TIMEOUT".

The script worked quite well until I decided to redirect the output of the executed program.

When the stdout and stderr are being redirected, the program executed by the script is not being killed because it has a pid different than the one I got from fork.

It seems perl executes a shell that executes my program in the case of redirection.

I would like to have the output redirection but still be able to kill the program in the case of a timeout.

Any ideas on how I could do that?

A simplified code of my script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

my $timeout = 5;
my $cmd = "very_long_program 1>&2 > out.txt";

my $pid = fork();
if( $pid == 0 )
{
   exec($cmd) or print STDERR "Couldn't exec '$cmd': $!";
   exit(2);
}
my $time = 0;
my $kid = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
while ( $kid == 0 )
{
   sleep(1);
   $time ++;
   $kid = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
   print "Waited $time sec, result $kid\n";
   if ($timeout > 0 && $time > $timeout)
   {
      print "TIMEOUT!\n";
      #Kill process
      kill 9, $pid;
      exit(3);
   }
}

if ( $kid == -1)
{
   print "Process did not exist\n";
   exit(4);
}
print "Process exited with return code $?\n";
exit($?);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing `$cmd` from

```
my $cmd = "very_long_program 1>&2 > out.txt";
```

to

```
my $cmd = "exec very_long_program 1>&2 > out.txt";
```

The `exec` will tell the shell that gets spawned by perl to replace itself with very_long_program, rather than running very_long_program as a child.

(The reason perl spawns a shell in this case is because `$cmd` contains the redirect characters - and perl doesn't know how to handle them itself. An alternative way of solving the problem is to do the redirection in perl itself after the `fork()` but prior to calling `exec()` - but that's slightly trickier, so try the `exec` workaround first!)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to redirect STDOUT and STDERR after the fork and run the command without the redirection:

```
open(STDOUT, ">", "out.txt") or die "Err: $!";
open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
exec("very_long_command");
die "Failed to exec very_long_command: $!";
```